Can Islamic banking be considered "following their ways"?
Is one allowed to open a bank account in a bank that follows Islamic customs and poses itself as Islamic banking? The card they offer would be not usable for purchases in stores that are designated for the sole purpose of using alcohol, gambling facilities, no interest, etc.
Would having their card be following their ways and assur?

Welcome to MiYodeya Danish and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Are Jewish people who live in islamic countries not using banks that follow sharia?

What "way" is one following? Not gambling or purchasing wine with a credit card?

Well imposing their set of limitations. And the card is not a credit card. Also it is advertised to be for those who follow their faith and what if owning their card as if an approval of their ways? Also their bank prohibits funds circulating to be invested into such things as gambling and alcohol etc. The card has particular design so somebody might think you associate with their faith by using the product spefically catered to them? Imagine it was Xtian banking with limitations of of paying in clubs and a design of a card in simple shapes but which could be recognized as Xtian

I really can't see an issue here. Islam is not "avodah zarah"; the issue would maybe kinda sorta be "avoid the ways of the non-Jews", but I just don't see this as one of them. That's defined essentially as something you'd only be doing to try and fit in with the non-Jews. Look, for centuries of coexistence we did kosher slaughter with the animal facing the qibla (i.e. the direction of Mecca), if that's what the locals demanded. The meat's still kosher. And this banking thing sounds a lot more kosher than that.

Maybe they can say after "see how our ways are superior if even a Jew chooses to use our banking". Of course there would be no issue of getting interest on the remaining funds on Shabbos as a plus. But overall if I to use it wouldn't they at some point say oh look it's as if that one agrees that our ways are right. The case is ordinary banking is for everyone but they cater to those who adhere to islam. So wouldn't I be promoting their faith inadvertently by having an item attached to a service which is knowingly advertised as a  islamic product which functions under the sharia basically

In the USA there’s a thing called a health share that is run by a Christian church. Jewish’s people used it until they added a clause that you had to sign that you agree to their principals which some had an issue with. Is there such a statement in the card agreement?

Funding terror or anti-semitism might be a bigger issue though...

@DanishDarish "they can say after 'see how our ways are superior if even a Jew chooses to use our banking'" - they could also, by the same token, say "...if even a Jew chooses to use our [Arabic] language" - and maybe even more so, since their model for perfect Arabic is the Koran. Yet that obviously doesn't make it forbidden for Jews in Islamic countries to speak Arabic.

You think it would be assur to not buy alcohol?
